# Create a stored procedure in Starburst Enterprise

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, starburst

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Starburst Enterprise. But even after going through the documentation I am not able to find the syntax for it. I am not new to Starburst tool. Is it possible to create the stored procedure in starburst enterprise?